# Spring OAuth2 Client grant_type=password example

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0

I am looking for a Spring OAuth2 Client example that uses `grant_type=password`. I know how it works in Postman and I have Authorization Server and Resource server setup working with Postman. I can't find any samples for Spring OAuth2 Client using the password grant. Can anyone point me to the right direction?

Answer (score -1):

I was able to find an example of authorization_code flow so closing this question
[Here is tutorialspoint link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring_security/spring_security_with_oauth2.htm)

Comment: OP was asking about the Resource Owner Password Credentials flow, so a tutorial about authorization_code flow is not relevant